# pyramid pooling and max pooling in convolution neural network

Tags: neural-network, convolution, pooling

I would like to use Gaussian pyramid for pooling in convolution neural network. The target for this is to build a decovolution network to reconstruct the input(a image). That is to say when I obtain a convolution neural network model to generate some feature, then the original image can be reconstructed by the decovolution network. In the convnet, the common max pooling operation is non-invertible which is the reason to use Gaussian pyramid pooling. I have google the internet, but it seem that pyramid pooling is rarely used in convolution neural network.

So I would to know the difference between max pooling and pyramid pooling. What is the drawback of pyramid pooling in convolution neural network.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is primarily aimed at answering questions about programming, while your question is mostly a theoretical one about the performance of a machine learning model. You might want to ask your question on another stackexchange site like [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com). There is also [Meta Optimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa) for machine learning questions.